# Amazon S3 Can't Delete Object via API

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm setting up a new policy so my website can store images on S3, and I'm trying to keep it as secure as possible.

I can put an object and read it, but can not delete it, even though it appears I've followed the recommendations from Amazon. I am not using versioning.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListObjects"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you delete the object via other means (besides the API)?

Comment: @PrestonM Yes, I can delete through the control panel.

Answer (score 1):

After screwing around with multiple permission actions it turns out I needed to add `s3:ListBucket` and `s3:ListObjects`. Once added I can now delete objects.